# Create windows form application in vs express 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want to create a windows form app in c#. It's supposed to be simple but I can't find the option in the menue. In the new project window, instead of the regular options such windows form application, console application ect, I have: blank app, class library, windows runtime and unit test app.
Someone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

try this. click ctrl+shift+n, under templates click the arrow next to Visual C#, then choose Windows. the option will then be in the middle window.

Comment: It deosn't exist there. Here is a screen shot: http://forumpics.a7.org/?file=20170129102728.png

Comment: Close all instance of Visual Studio. Open visual studio command prompt and type: devenv.exe /vsinstalltemplates

Comment: I get: 'devenv.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: click your start menu and look for the visual studio folder. in that folder you should see "developer command prompt for visual studio". click and then enter that command. you cant use the windows cmd.

Comment: Problem solved. I had vs for win 10. Now I installed vs for windows desktop and everything is in place.

Comment: I didn't know they had two different versions of vs. but reinstalling is also another way to solve that issue.